# How to organize private methods on Perl objects?

Tags: perl, oop

What is the correct way to handle methods which will not be called by the user? For example if the user calls a method, say `do_stuff()` from a driver script, and if `do_stuff()` relies on other subroutines, is it best practice to call those subs from within the `do_stuff()` method as follows:

```
sub do_stuff {
    my ( $self, %arg ) = @_;
    #does it things
    #and then calls the private sub as follows
    _private_sub( $self, %arg );
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734385/how-do-i-define-private-or-internal-methods-in-object-oriented-perl

Comment: there doesn't seem to me to be any reason not to just call it as `$self->_private_sub(%arg)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `do_stuff` method needs the functionality that you decided should be kept "private" then by all means call `_private_sub` within it.  That is precisely its purpose.  Of course, having a sub be "private" is a matter of convention as it cannot be enforced.

I'd like to mention another way, of using coderefs for private subs

```
my $_private = sub { ... };  # must be at least predeclared

sub do_stuff {
    my ($self, %arg) = @_;
    # ...
    my $from_private = $self->$_private->(@args);    # or
    my $more_private = $_private->($self, @args);
}
```

The syntax is odd but that surely warns the users that it is a private method. This makes it hard for subclasses to inherit, thanks to [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) for emphasizing this.

The second invocation uses `$_private` as a *function* rather than a method, so we have to pass the object if it needs it. This further warns against its use. Then it also doesn't undergo the normal method lookup process (and is thus slightly faster), something to be well aware of.

I am a little uncertain as to what exactly the question seeks.

If it is about whether to use "private" subroutines in your code, then there is really no accepted best practice.  They are very useful, but they are not truly private.  I use them, liberally.

A full answer is to use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1807/lib/Moose.pm) or [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Moo-2.003000/lib/Moo.pm), or some other module.

Comment: Doesn't that make it hard for subclasses to inherit your private method?

Comment: @mob Well, it does, thus the warning. It still can be a choice, for those that will not be subclassed.  Are you saying that it shouldn't be used really (as  a matter of "good practices")?

Comment: No, but I am saying I just learned that `$sqrt=sub{sqrt($_[0])}; print 9->$sqrt` will actually output 3!

Comment: @mob Huh ... ?? ... um, it does work!  I don't get it (yet -- don't tell me please! :).

Comment: While you are at it, look up mst's talk *you did what?* on YouTube. :-)

Comment: BTW, Moose doesn't help here. It makes everything more convenient, but it is also just Perl. There is hardly any magic involved and it cannot make things private.

Comment: @simbabque  Thank you, I'll look it up.  As for Moose, I didn't think one can make it _truly_ private (but I did hope for something close to it) -- but I mean that it must stimulate a different mind set. I don't use it day to day but I'd expect it to focus one on a far higher level and then it may simply never come to all kinds of picky decisions. (I'm inching toward picking up a module for regular use, toward Moo.)

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there's no "correct" way. Perl doesn't provide the ability to hide the functions, at least that I've ever run across. What I've done is use a naming standard where I start the internal-only function names with an underscore and clearly document that they're never to be called by external callers.

EDIT: The other answers triggered a thought. In each private method, you could check the results of the "caller ()" function and abort if the caller is anyone other than the local module. Honestly, I personally wouldn't go to the trouble, but if it's really important to you for some reason, that would emphasize the private nature of these methods.

Comment: I think you're right, and your convention of using a leading underscore is widely used.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to `$self->_private_sub(...)`? In my mind, the `$obj->_method` notation is always used with function that act on an instance of your class, and other kinds of calls are always used for other kinds of functions.

But if you're going to be paranoid, why not use an unconventional way of packing your arguments that will confound anyone that tries to use your private method in an object oriented way?

```
sub do_stuff {
    my ( $self, %arg ) = @_;
    ...
    _private_sub( %arg, $self );
}

sub _private_sub {
    my $self = pop;
    my %args = @_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, this is a real mind-job :)  (Just ... they'll probably look it up in the source and still go ahead)

Comment: That is horrible. Private or not, security through obscurity is hardly a good idea. This will make your maintenance programmer hate you (remember that could be you), and stuff will break every time a user (or you) tries to call that `_private_sub` as a method. Mixing methods and functions in one class should not be the way to go.

Comment: I often wish I could upvote my own answers, but yeah, sometimes I wish I could downvote them, too.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers you have received so far say that it can't be done. But it can - in Perl 5.18 and later. See the [section on lexical subroutines in `perldoc perlsub`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines).

> **Lexical Subroutines**
>
> **WARNING:** Lexical subroutines are still experimental. The feature may be modified or removed in future versions of Perl.
>
> Lexical subroutines are only available under the `use feature 'lexical_subs'` pragma, which produces a warning unless the "experimental::lexical_subs" warnings category is disabled.
>
> Beginning with Perl 5.18, you can declare a private subroutine with `my` or `state`. As with state variables, the state keyword is only available under `use feature 'state'` or `use 5.010` or higher.
>
> These subroutines are only visible within the block in which they are declared, and only after that declaration:
>
> ```
> no warnings "experimental::lexical_subs";
> use feature 'lexical_subs'; 
>
> foo();              # calls the package/global subroutine
>
> state sub foo {
>   foo();            # also calls the package subroutine
> }
>
> foo();              # calls "state" sub
> my $ref = \&foo;    # take a reference to "state" sub
>
> my sub bar { ... }
> bar();              # calls "my" sub
> ```
>
> To use a lexical subroutine from inside the subroutine itself, you must predeclare it. The `sub foo {...}` subroutine definition syntax respects any previous `my sub;` or `state sub;` declaration.
>
> ```
> my sub baz;         # predeclaration
> sub baz {           # define the "my" sub
>   baz();            # recursive call
> }
> ```